# Ctrl+space autocompletion for TernJS (ST3)

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I have a problem getting `Ctrl+space` autocompletion working per TernJS description (Sublime Text 3).

Autocompletion as such seems to work, because if I define `bbb` variable as string per below, type `.t`, then the list of string methods with names starting with `t` does open (like `.toLowerCase()` below that was produced by autocompletion).

However, I can't open a full list of autocompletions by pressing `Ctrl+space`. Is there some reason for it, like a limit? How can I get the full list of object methods using TernJS?

[image]

Console messages seem to suggest that the plugin is working correctly:

```
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-jshint.linter
SublimeLinter: jshint linter loaded 
reloading plugin TernJS.tern
reloading plugin View In Browser.ViewInBrowserCommand
reloading plugin JSHint.JSHint
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.commands
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.sublimelinter
plugins loaded
TernJS: No need to update PyV8
Syncing project /home/auser/learn/js/learn1/learn1.sublime-project
Starting TernJS server for /home/auser/learn/js/learn1/learn1.sublime-project with 4 libs and 1 files
Syncing project empty
Starting TernJS server for empty with 1 libs and 0 files
SublimeLinter: debug mode: off 
SublimeLinter: jshint activated: /usr/local/bin/jshint 
warning: mnemonic t not found in menu caption Tools
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-07-14
```

Comment: What do  you mean by: "can't open a full list of autocompletions by pressing `Ctrl+space`?" Looks like you on linux, perhaps you mean `Alt+/`.